# Is the sum of this series convergent? and how to find the sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I don't know if this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find how to prove that the sum of this series is convergent, this series is actually the area hyperbolic tangent function.
An additional question is: if this series is convergent, then how to find the sum of it?

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}(x)^{2n+1}$

suppose that $x = 2$

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}(2)^{2n+1}$

Comment: So you see that the series certainly does not converge for every value of $x$.  Try to find the radius of convergence of the series using the ratio test.

Comment: Hint: Geometric Series

Comment: You need some fiddling around to use the ratio test, but Hadamard's formula always works. Whichever way you choose, can you find the radius of convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider 
$$
S = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n} = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + \ldots = \frac{1}{1-x^2} \\
\implies \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}x^{2n+1} = \int\limits_{0}^x S \ \mathrm{d}x
= \int\limits_{0}^x\frac{1}{1-x^2} \mathrm{d}x
$$

The last integration can be easily done using partial fractions. It will, like you said, turn out to be $$\tanh^{-1}x$$

Also, the series is convergent wherever the original geometric series is convergent i.e., when

$$\left|x\right| < 1$$

You can also prove the convergence by using D'Alembert's ratio test.

Comment: @Jonathan Y Yeah, Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\left|\frac{x^{2n+3}}{2n+3}\frac{2n+1}{x^{2n+1}}\right|=\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}|x|^2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|x|^2<1\iff\ldots$$

$$f(x):=\frac1{1-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}\implies f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}\ldots$$